# ReactiveCocoa subscribeNext for Optionals in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I wrote an extension on `RACSignal` for a lot of the common ReactiveCocoa operations, `map`, `filter`, `subscribeNext` so that I could explicitly specify the type in the callback block. `map` became `mapAs`, `filter` became `filterAs` and `subscribeNext` become `subscribeNextAs` (etc, etc)

```
func subscribeNextAs<T>(nextClosure:(T) -> ()) -> RACDisposable! {
   return self.subscribeNext {
        (next) -> () in
        if let nextAsT = next as? T {
            nextClosure(nextAsT)
        }
    }
}
```

One of the problems I noticed however is that optional values weren't getting passed through to `nextClosure` and rightly so because the `if let nextAsT` fails.

How could I rewrite this extension function so that `subscribeNextAs` allows me to cast both optionals and non-optionals?

Example:

```
RACObserve(someObject, potentiallyOptionalTitle).subscribeNextAs({
    (next: String?) in
})
RACObserve(someObject, nonOptionalTitle).subscribeNextAs({
    (next: String) in
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the optionality of your generic type for your `nextClosure` parameter. In your case, you can define your generic `subscribeNext` as:

```
func subscribeNextAs<T>(nextClosure:(T!) -> ()) -> RACDisposable {
   return self.subscribeNext {
        (next) -> () in
           nextClosure(next != nil ? next as! T : nil)
    }
}
```

The drawback here is that the optionality is hidden, meaning that you wont' be able to guarantee at compile time wether your appropriately handling nil values.
You'll have to be careful not to pass in nil values where you don't expect those.

Another option would be to use upgrade to RAC 4.x and use generic `Signal<T>` but it still in Alpha, so don't do that if you're release to prod.

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribeNext` takes a closure of type `(AnyObject!)->Void`. This `AnyObject!` can't be cast to `String?`. Try this code in a playgroud:

```
let str: String? = "1"
str is String? // true

let anyObjStr: AnyObject? = "1"
anyObjStr is String? // false, not the same type
anyObjStr is String // true, the unwrapped value can be cast to String
anyObjStr is NSString // true
```

To solve this problem, you can *add* an overload of your method with optional parameter:

```
func subscribeNextAs<T>(nextClosure:(T?) -> ()) -> RACDisposable! {
    return self.subscribeNext {
        (next) -> () in
        if let unwrapped = next {
            if let nextAsT = unwrapped as? T {
                nextClosure(nextAsT)
            }
        } else {
            nextClosure(nil)
        }
    }
}
```